# AWS RDS CLI: DB instances not listed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I've created an IAM user (CLI only) with `AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess` permissions. Now every time I try to list my db instances I get an empty JSON object, even though I have one active RDS instance:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances
{
    "DBInstances": []
}
```

Also I tried to specify my instance id (the instance identifier does exist for sure):

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier mydb
An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) when calling the \
DescribeDBInstances operation: DBInstance vipbilet-db not found.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you’re querying a **wrong region**. Try `aws --region us-east-1 rds describe-db-instances`. Replace *us-east-1* with the region where you have your instance.